# Forcing SSL and www in .htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirects, https, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a way to force SSL and `www`.

I've been able to force both separately but together I keep running into redirection issues. The following code works when handling a URL in this format: `http://example.com` and properly redirects to `https://www.example.com` but when the incoming URL is `https://example.com` it will not forward to `https://www.example.com` - Any suggestions?

EDIT: it should also send `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127\.0\.0\.0
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first line is used to prevent internal URL's from being rewritten. That might cause different pages to be displayed, so I've removed it.

If the host is `example.com` or is not requested over HTTPS, it will be rewritten to `https://example.com/`. I.e., it rewrites `http://example.com`, `http://www.example.com` and `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` in one action.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

[Documentation on mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

If you've subdomains like `forum.example.com`, the first rule should be as is. Otherwise, you can do a negative match against `www.example.com` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the third line have to be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127\.0\.0\.0
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following lines that I use and work flawlessly.

(Remove the top RewriteCond if you do not use CloudFlare)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"' [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implemented this for my site. Works like a charm!
Added to the top of my .htaccess file.
Redirects all instances of people typing www or not www, http or https.

```
# BEGIN HTTPS Redirect
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
# END HTTPS Redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested all the suggestions given above, but none covered the whole scenario.

I wanted all the visitors to go to `https://www.example1.com/`

Some of the codes provided by other users worked to take non-secure and/or non-www URL to `https://www.example1.com/`, however, none of them covered `https://example1.com` to be converted to "www" as well.

I have my website hosted with GoDaddy, in case this makes any difference.

This is the code that worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example1.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The last line could be also:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example1.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But I used the code "301" to send the message "[moved permanently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)" in the hope that Google and maybe other search engines will update old links.